# Dividing all but first element of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to divide all the elements of a column matrix but the first.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.matrix(np.ones((5,1)))
>>> t
matrix([[ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.]])
```

My aim is obtain a new matrix (say n) which is of same dimensions as t with all but first element of t divided by a number (say 5)

```
>>> n
matrix([[1.],
        [0.2],
        [0.2],
        [0.2],
        [0.2]])
```

I'm new to numpy. Can someone help me on how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> n = t.copy()
>>> n[1:] /= 5
>>> n
matrix([[ 1. ],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2]])
```

alternatively,

```
>>> np.vstack([t[0], t[1:]/5])
matrix([[ 1. ],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2],
        [ 0.2]])
```